# ASP.NET Core - Send email without wait

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, sendgrid

I have an APS.NET Core 5 Web API:

I have this:

```
await _mailSender.SendMailAsync(entity.Id);
```

But, I don't want to wait for the email sender to *return Ok* for client.
I want to continue code execution and send email in background.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can await it later in your code. But be careful with a fire-and-forget, if e.g. a dependency gets cleaned up.

Comment: @Jeppe sorry, but I didn´t understand.

Comment: `await` will, from this thread's perspective, wait for the email to be sent before continuing and e.g. finishing the api-request. Remove the `await`, and it will continue to finish the api-request immediately. But injected services have lifetimes - so if `_mailSender` depends on a scoped service, I think there's a risk of that dependency getting cleaned up before you're done. You could create a `EmailQueue` singleton, on which you can enqueue tasks. It can then maintain its own dependency lifecycle.

Comment: @Jeppe I understand it now! Can you send me an EmailQueue singleton example pls?

Comment: FYI, SendGrid queues your email when you submit it to their API and then returns you with 'Ok'. Shortly after SendGrid will actually send the email. So you're not really waiting for the email to be sent. Not sure if this changes your mind about awaiting or not, but wanted to make sure you knew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using HangFire to queue the email to send.

```
//send email
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _mailSender.SendMailAsync(entity.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `Task` class, you can execute a single operation asynchronously.

Try this code:

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => _mailSender.SendMailAsync(entity.Id).Result;
```

The work performed by a `Task` object typically executes asynchronously on a thread pool thread rather than synchronously on the main application thread.